# google.script.host.close to close a dialog box not working

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to close a modeless dialog that I opened with the following:

```
var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('dialog')
.setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
.setWidth(150)
.setHeight(150);
DocumentApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(html, 'Help');
```

The dialog html looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
   <head>
    <base target="_top">
   </head>
    <body>
     Working on it...
   </body>
 </html>
```

Now I want to close the dialog, but I can't get it to work.  This is what I have.

```
var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('close');
```

And the close html looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
   <head>
     <base target="_top">
     <script>
       google.script.host.close();
     </script>
   </head>
   <body>
   </body>
 </html>
```

I've tried the google.script.host.close with the '()' and without.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: So, is the "close.html" file being displayed?  You might try changing the code to `window.onload = function() {google.script.host.close();}`  I'm guessing that you want "close.html" to close as soon as it is opened?

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty easily fixed issue as far as I can see. You don't want to create a new HTML file to close the old one, you want to close the first one. What you should do is this.

First, open your dialog as you have been doing.

Second, put your host.close() in a function inside of your help.html:

```
function closeHelp() {
  google.script.host.close();
};
```

Then, just find somewhere to close it. I normally just make a button at the bottom of any dialog box.

```
<button onclick="closeHelp()"> Close </button>
```

This will close your window.

Answer (score 0):

An example of a script that closes a notification HtmlService after 3 seconds

```
function t2 () {
var output = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<b>Thanks for the feedback.<br><br>'
+'<p><input type="button" value="Close" onclick="google.script.host.close()" /></p></b>'
+'<script> setTimeout(function(){ google.script.host.close(); }, 3000); </script>')
.setWidth(300)
.setHeight(100);
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(output, 'Completed');
}
```